# Using Interval expressions with bash extended globbing

Tags: bash, shell

I know for a fact, that `bash` supports extended glob with a regular expression like support for `@(foo|bar)`, `*(foo)` and `?(foo)`. This syntax is quite unique i.e. different from that of EREs -- extended globs use a prefix notation (where the operator appears `before` its operands), rather than postfix like EREs.

I'm wondering does it support the interval expressions feature of type `{n,m}` i.e. if there is one number in the braces, the preceding regexp is repeated `n` times or if there are two numbers separated by a comma, the preceding regexp is repeated `n` to `m` times. I couldn't find a particular documentation that suggests this support enabled in extended glob.

#### Actual Question

I came across a requirement in one of the questions today, to remove only a pair of trailing zeroes in a string. Trying to solve this with the extended glob support in `bash`

Given some sample strings like

```
foobar0000
foobar00
foobar000
```

should produce

```
foobar00
foobar
foobar0
```

I tried using extended glob with parameter expansion to do

```
x='foobar000'
```

respectively. I tried using the interval expression as below which seemed obvious to me that it wouldn't work

```
echo ${x%%+([0]{2})}
```

i.e. similar using `sed` in ERE as `sed -E 's/[0]{2}$//'` or in BRE as `sed 's/[0]\{2\}$//'`

So my question being, is this possible using any of the extended glob operators? I'm looking for answers specific to using the extended glob support in `bash` would take 'No' if not possible too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow I managed to find a way to do this within the confinements of `bash`.

### Are interval glob-expressions implemented in bash?

No! In contrast to other shells such as ksh and zsh, bash did not implement interval expressions for globbing.

### Can we mimic interval expressions in bash?

Yes! However, it is not really practical and could sometimes benefit by using `printf`. The idea is to build the globular expression that mimics the `{m,n}` interval using the KSH-globs `@(pattern)` and `?(pattern)`.

In the explanation below, we assume that the pattern is stored in variable `p`

- ***Match `n` occurrences of the given pattern (`{n}`):***

  The idea is to repeat the pattern `n` times. For large *n* you can use `printf`

  ```
  $ var="foobar01010"
  $ echo ${var%%@(0|1)@(0|1)}
  foobar000
  ```

  or

  ```
  $ var="foobar01010"
  $ p=$(printf "@(0|1)%.0s" {1..4})
  $ echo ${var%%$p}
  foobar0
  ```
- ***Match at least `m` occurrences of the given pattern (`{m,}`):***

  It is the same as before, but with an additional `*(pattern)`

  ```
  $ var="foobar01010"
  $ echo ${var%%@(0|1)@(0|1)*(0|1)}
  foobar
  ```

  or

  ```
  $ var="foobar01010"
  $ p="(0|1)"
  $ q=$(printf "@$p%.0s" {1..4})
  $ echo ${var%%$q*$p}
  foobar
  ```
- ***Match from `n` to `m` occurrences of the given pattern (`{m,n}`):***

  The interval expression `{n,m}` implies we have for sure *n* appearances and *m-n* possible appearances. These can be constructed using the ksh-globs `@(pat)` *n* times and `?(pat)` *m-n* times. For *n=2* and *m=3*, this leads to:

  ```
  $ var="foobar01010"
  $ echo ${var%%@(0|1)@(0|1)?(0|1)}
  foobar010
  ```

  or

  ```
  $ p="(0|1)"
  $ q=$(printf "@$p%.0s" {1..n})$(printf "?$p%.0s" {n+1..m})
  $ echo ${var%%$q}
  foobar010
  $ var="foobar00200"
  foobar002
  $ var="foobar00020"
  foobar00020
  ```

  Another way to construct the interval expression `{n,m}` is using the ksh-glob *anything but pattern* written as `!(pat)` which allows us to say: give me all, except...

  > **`man bash`:**
  >   `!(pattern-list)`: Matches anything except one of the given patterns

  This way we can write

  ```
  $ echo ${var%%!(!(*$p)|@$p@$p@$p+$p|?$p)}
  ```

  or

  ```
  $ p="(0|1)"
  $ pn=$(printf "@$p%.0s" {1..n})
  $ pm=$(printf "?$p%.0s" {1..m-1})
  $ echo ${var%%!(!(*$p)|$pn+$p|$pm)}
  ```

  **note:** you need to do a double exclusion here due to the *or* (`|`) in the pattern list.

### What about other shells?

#### KSH93

The interval expression `{n,m}` has been implemented in `ksh93`:

> **`man ksh`:**
>
> - `{n}(pattern-list)`   Matches `n` occurrences of the given patterns.
> - `{m,n}(pattern-list)` Matches from `m` to `n` occurrences of the given patterns.  If `m` is omitted, `0` will be used.  If `n` is omitted at least `m` occurrences will be matched.

```
$ echo ${var%%{2,3}(0|1)}
```

#### ZSH

Also `zsh` has a form of interval expression. It is a globbing flag which is part of the `EXTENDED_GLOB` option:

> **`man zshall`:**
>
> `(#cN,M)`   The flag `(#cN,M)` can be used anywhere that the `#` or `##` operators can be used except in the expressions `(*/)#` and `(*/)##` in filename generation, where `/` has special meaning; it cannot be combined with  other globbing flags and a bad pattern error occurs if it is misplaced.  It is equivalent to the form `{N,M}` in regular expressions.  The previous character or group is required to match between `N` and `M` times, inclusive.  The form
>                 `(#cN)` requires exactly `N` matches; `(#c,M)` is equivalent to specifying `N` as `0`; `(#cN,)` specifies that there is no maximum limit on the number of matches.

```
$ echo ${var%%(0|1)(#c2,3)}
```

Answer (score 1):

- No
- "Extended pattern matching features" is enabled using extglob (thus we call that extended glob). Extended pattern matching features are used in an operation called [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching). Pattern matching is used in [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) and in `[[...]]` [conditional constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) when using `=` or `!=` operators. Filename expansion is used in parameter expansion.
- As you can see in [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching), extended glob or not, pattern matching does not support expressions like `[set]{count}`. We can for example match one or more occurrences with `+(..)` and so on, but specifying the number of occurrences of a pattern is not possible.
- But this is bash and bash is powerful. We can specify the number of occurrences of a pattern simply by repeating the pattern. We cannot specify the ending or the beginning (I mean like using `^` and `$` in regex), but we can use `${parameter%%word}` parameter expansions to remove the trailing portion of the parameter. So this will work:

```
var='foobar000'
echo ${var%%[0][0]}
```

and, with some simple hacking, we can do this:

```
var='foobar000'
echo ${var%%$(yes '[0]' | head -n 2 | tr -d '\n')}
```

and this will remove two trailing zeros from the string.